# Google maps (v3) get geolocate address into directions - gives status OK, but no directions (target not found)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So I'm trying to to this:

- Enter an address
- Get the lat/long for the address
- put it in "directions" with final destination (lat/long)
- get directions in my two div's

Sound easy enough. This script gives back status "OK". So you should think it would work, but no.

```
<div id="map_canvas" class="pic50"></div>
<div id="map_directions" class="text50"></div>

bring_me_back('map_canvas','map_directions','some address');
<script>
// bring me back
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function bring_me_back(call_back_map,call_back_directions,address) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.764696,5.526042); // where you're at
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(call_back_map),myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById(call_back_directions));
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title:"My location"
  });

  // find the address
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder (map);
    geocoder.geocode ( { 'address': address }, function(results, status)  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)  {
        var end = results [0].geometry.location; // where you need to go
      map.setCenter(results [0].geometry.location);
      marker.setPosition(results [0].geometry.location);
          var start = "51.764696,5.526042"; // where you're at (random place)
          var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
             alert("Directions was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          });
    } 
    else {
      $('#'+call_back).html("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

I know I'm doing something stupid cause my error console says: Target: [my website]# was not found

Funny thing though, the map does center on the correct place of geolocator with a marker. So except for push back the directions it does fine (i think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do anything in the DirectionsService callback routine other than output the message "Directions was not successful for the following reason: " + status:

```
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
         alert("Directions was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      });
```

If you want to display the route, you need to call the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#RenderingDirections)

Try something like this:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  } else  alert("Directions was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
});
```

Comment: See, I did something stupid. I thought I had it covered with "directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById(call_back_directions));".
Works like a charm, Thanks!